# How to Load One Single Page like Login.js as Home page without using App.js

Tags: react-native

I am very new to react-native. I am just trying to make one Sample Login Page creating from/src/pages/login.js. And I am not using app.js.

But somehow my page is not loading showing blank screen sometimes error like script not loading properly or, app loading

my code for Login.js
  (This is just a sample Testing I am doing).

```
export default class Login extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
     return (

     <View>
        <Text> This Is login Page</Text>
      </View>

      );   
   }
}
```

Index.js

```
   import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

   import App from './App';

   import {name as appName} from './app.json';

    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Login from './src/pages/Login';

type Props = {};

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
     return (
            <View><Login/></View>
       );
    }
}
```

what to do, What I am doing wrong. just want to load from folder pages, not from app.js.

Thanks in Advance.

[Error all the time whenever i m doing changes in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEpE0.png)

Comment: can you add contents of index.js from your root folder?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani - added index.js and app.js

Comment: make sure you give path correctly…

Comment: which path i gave wrong? please let me know

Comment: @Tanveerbyn - Thanks.Yes i was wrongly importing the components. and also two default exports there in file.That y it was not loading. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add flex:1 in  style in view it will work

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
export default class Login extends Component<Props> {

       render() {

       return (

     <View style={{flex:1}}>

      <Text> This Is login Page</Text>

      </View>

                  );

         }

}
```

Comment: You have to add App.js because bundle calls first App.js. You can import your file in App.js to load

Comment: Helal Anaik. Ok let me try then.

Comment: Ok.let me know if you face trouble!

Comment: No luck. Still error    wat i did in my app.js     
'code'  import Login from    './src/pages/Login';
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
      <Login/>  </View>
    );
  }
}

Comment: Same error? are your import path is right because I run your code here it's working fine

Comment: yes, its correct-since morning i am trying but no luck.stucked

Comment: Have you checked your metro bundler screen?  origin of this type of error generally shown there.